# Qt call java method with more than 1 argument

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I examining the Qt Notifier example for android: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html
In this example, a Java method is called with 2 parameters, like this:

```
void NotificationClient::updateAndroidNotification()
{
    QAndroidJniObject javaNotification = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(m_notification);
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org/qtproject/example/notification/NotificationClient",
                                       "notify",
                                       "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                       javaNotification.object<jstring>());
}
```

I am having hard time understanding what parameters I should pass in here to call the function with 2 parameters, not one. For instance, the function currently takes 1 parameter:

```
public static void notify(String s)
{
    if (m_notificationManager == null) {
        m_notificationManager = 

(NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
            m_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
        }

        m_builder.setContentText(s);
        m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
    }
```

I can add another one in the method itself ( `public static void notify(String s, String x)` ), but how to handle the cpp part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org/qtproject/example/notification/NotificationClient",
                                   "notify",
                                   "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                   javaNotification.object<jstring>(), 
                                   somethingelse.object<jstring>());
```

as explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#details).